# Priorities the traffic using TC

Tags: linux, controls, traffic, qos

I would like to Traffic Control TC to priorities the traffic. For example I need the TCP goes via band0, UDP goes via band1, and other traffic goes via band3.

I create the qdisc as follows:

tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio 
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 20: sfq
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 30: sfq

but when I add filter, e.g.

tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:1 sfq 1 u32 match ip protocol 6 0xff flowid 1:10

There was a problem "Unknown filter "sfq", hence option "1" is unparsable"

Answer (score 0):

Without 'sfq 1'.
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:1 u32 match ip protocol 6 0xff flowid 1:10